# Send all balance to multiple destinations using the rpc?

Tags: rpc, sweep-transaction, typescript

I'm using the ts integration of the RPC, and was wondering if it's possible to send the whole balance like the sweeping do, but to multiple wallets?

I know it's possible to send to multiple addresses and set the amount.
The problem is when trying to send all the balance, it don't auto calculate the fees and is a pain in the ass to get it done.

EDIT: or include the fees in the amount sent

Comment: What "ts integration" are you using? The official wallet RPC one would use is `transfer_split` ([ref](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer_split)).